# Colocar texto imagens etc... na ordem horizontal

Tags: bootstrap, css

Como posso colocar o componente do `Bootstrap` *Thumbnails* na ordem horizontal? E como posso aumentar o tamanho deles (com a imagem junto) para um tamanho que eu quero? Se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para alterar o tamanho você pode utilizar o `col-md`.

Comment: Qual é o código para ficar lado a lado? E não tem como aumentar a altura do col-md? Pois ele só aumenta a largura :(

Comment: @Vinicius você deixa as imagens lado a lado com o `col-md` esse é o sistema de grids do bootstrap, são divididos em 12 partes. Para mudar o tamanho você pode usar o `width` na imagem, mas cuidado para não deixar a visualização da imagem prejudicada com isso.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado.